# Making animation smoother

Tags: plotting, animation

```
s = NDSolve[{
Derivative[1][x][t] == (40/14) x[t] - y[t] z[t] + 18,
Derivative[1][y][t] == -10 y[t] + x[t] z[t],
Derivative[1][z][t] == -4 z[t] + x[t] y[t],
x[0] == 1, z[0] == 1, y[0] == 1},
{x, y, z},
{t, 0, 40},
MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]
];

Animate[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. s],
  {t, 0, tend},
  ImageSize -> 700,
  Boxed -> False,
  PlotPoints -> 2000,
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors", #3] &),
  PlotRange -> {{-16, 25}, {-20, 25}, {-2, 40}}
 ],
{tend, .1, 200},
AnimationRate -> 1
]
```

This animation is very jerky.  I would like the line to progress more smoothly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Animate` should be jerky with long calculations.

You might want to store the frames in a `Table` and use `ListAnimate`, instead.

The difference is that `Animate` does calculations *inbetween* frames, meaning it:

- Displays a frame;
- Generates the next one;
- Displays a frame;
- Generates the next one;

and so on. And depending on how hard the frame generation process and how good your computer is, it can seriously affect the output speed and quality.

`ListAnimate`, on the other hand, uses a table of pre-generated frames and the only thing your program needs to do when `ListAnimate` is called is to display the already generated frames one by one and it goes more smoothly.

Comment: This is a great answer. The `PlotPoints->2000` are likely what really slows this down. If you require that setting, then computing it in real time would take forever. Computing it beforehand could still take quite a while, but the `ListAnimate` after should be smoother. Also wrapping `Rasterize` around your plots might speed up the rendering of the animation, as displaying a 2D image is faster than a 3D graphic (in my experience).